# MySqli connect in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using XAMPP, PHP Version 5.6.20 in Windows. When I  try to connect to mysqli using:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'yash', 'thepassword1', 'yashdb');
```

This error is showing:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'yash'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\tdc\config\setup.php on line 3

Comment: Can you access your database 'yash' in phpMyAdmin? XAMPP is just a shell that helped you install individual applications that work together. You need to make sure that mysql and php are both working independently.

Comment: my database name is 'yashdb', username is 'yash' and password is 'thepassword1' I am using XAMPP so using 'localhost'. I wanted to know how to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAMPP's default user is *"root"* with no password. If you didn't set anything in it, use this default. Please also check the name of the database as what mseifert said.

Comment: It's not recommended using root. Ever. Only ever in necessity.

Comment: It removed the error<br>$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'yashdb');<br>but how to use other usernames other than root?

Comment: @Darren I agree. But if she is just starting learning PHP w/ mysql, she can use it just for a jump-start.

Comment: @YashGulati add a user in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: yes I could use it for beginning but what If in future I needed to login in other users. I want user name as 'yash' with a password

Comment: I did added a full privileged user.

Comment: @YashGulati If you are saying about using a hosting server, it is set-up via the hosting provider's control panel and it has some difference on the user interface (so it depends on the hosting provider). But for XAMPP, you can use PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: @YashGulati well, that should work for now. But for security purposes, it is not encouraged to set a full privileged user. You can learn about these security concerns as you go along. For now, I suggest that you should focus on learning the basics first. Changing host username/password doesn't matter much for now.

Comment: ok thanks for helping @someone your  'root' with no password helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Verify in phpmyadmin (http://localhost/phpmyadmin/) that the user "yash" exists with the password you specified, and that this user has permissions on the "yashdb" database. If you are able to login with `msqli_connect()` using the "root" user, then this is a user/permissions error within MySQL.

Comment: there is a user name 'yash', host name '%' with privileges 'all privileges', since I checked all the privileges. and It is not  working even in no password also.

Comment: Can you verify the password? You may have to reset it in phpmyadmin to confirm it is what you want it to be. If you have no password set, then using a password to login will still fail.

Comment: I have done it a dozen of times, and even tried no password. I can access it as root but not with 'yash' which has full privileges.

Comment: in front of root it is written 'localhost' as host name but in front of 'yash' it is  written '%' as host name, could it be the matter?

Comment: "%" means that MySQL will allow connections from any host under the user "yash", so it should not prevent you from logging in. I would try creating a new user under phpmyadmin, and enabling the option `Create database with same name and grant all privileges`, then try to connect to that database with the new user in `mysqli_connect()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I got the answer I changed host name from 'Any host' to 'Local' which in turn changed the % sign of host name to localhost, now I can access with
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'yash', 'thepassword1', 'yashdb');
which it was refusing before.

 I solved the issue myselt :)

 By the way thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You con use PDO for connection:-

new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name;charset=utf8mb4', 'user_name', 'password');